# How can I seamlessly switch between IK/FK?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

How can I switch between IK/FK without having bones changing their transformation?
 I have forearm bone with IK constrained. Now I want to disable IK and rotate forearm.
[image]
 The problem is whenever I disable the IK constraint, the forearm moves to the side.[image]
 How can I disable IK without losing position ?

Answer (score 6):

Under the Rig Main Properties you have the IK/FK slider. Below that you have two options to snap the pose to either the IK or FK position.

[image]

p.s. I notice you are using the MetaRig to animate. Generally the MetaRig is used to generate a new rig with all the bells and whistles like IK/FK organised for you.

[image: Generate Rig]

The 'generation' also creates the Rig Layers which makes switching and controlling easier...

[image: Rig Layers]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the magnet icon that says FK->IK, it will move the controller to the other controllers position.

[image]
[image]