# How to apply FK/IK for certain keyframes?

Tags: inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I'm animating a charracter and need him to switch between IK and FK controls for a certain action, but there's no way to set that afaik. If you set it at IK, the entire animation for that body part will play in IK. If you try to change it to FK, it sets the entire animation for that body part to FK.

How do I say, start in IK at frame 1, switch to FK at frame 20, and back to IK in frame 40 and so forth?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65290/how-can-i-seamlessly-switch-between-ik-fk

Comment: I saw that answer and it doesn't apply to my question. It didn't even answer that person question who asked it, who is asking the same thing as me.  He's telling you how to snap the IK controller to the FK position for a specific frame while still ultimately using IK controls, but what I want to do is have my mesh switch from following the IK controls to FK for any amount of frames. It wouldn't be very efficient to keep snapping the IK to FK position for like 30+ frames at a time.